# Is there a way to detect a process called exec?

Tags: linux, freebsd, macos, darwin

I'm interested in programmatically monitoring the state of a process (that isn't my own, and isn't a child of my own process). Is there a counter that increments, or an identifier that changes, etc. whenever a given process undergoes `exec` (or one of its variants)? I have checked the headers for `sysctl`, `libproc.h`, etc., but I haven't been able to find anything along these lines.

Obviously the PID won't change, but the executable path, arguments, environment variables *might* change. I could poll these values, and detect changes in them. Any change indicates that an `exec` occurred, but it's also possible (though strange) that a process could call `exec` with the same executable, args and env, which wouldn't set off my alarm.

I'm ultimately interested in what Darwin does, but I'd love to hear about any similar mechanism that might exist in any of the *nixes. That would at least give me a jumping off point on further research

Comment: Look into `strace`.

Comment: Oh I should have been more clear. I meant programmatically, whether through `sysctl`, libproc, or some other system API

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor is right: on linux (one of your tags) you can  strace and attach it to another running pid, to see its system calls (such as: exec) and act accordingly. If you are on macos : see the info / manual page for : dtruss  (or dtrace ? for *bsd)

Comment: @OlivierDulac Not just Linux, I have seen it on Solaris, and BSD.

Comment: @Alexander If by grammatically you mean not-shell, the consider looking at the source code of `strace`. Also consider using `strace` as a helper program.

Answer (score 1):

depending on your os, you should probably use:

```
strace # on linux. you can attach to a pid (if you (as root?) have the rights to do so)
# you can also "follow its children" (using the appropriate options : `man strace` )
```

Equivalent (with different capabilities) exist also on other unixes (and could possibly be installed on your OS as well) :

```
dtrace # bsd originated, I believe. Should be present also on macos?

dtruss # on macos

truss # on aix
```

etc.

For each: you will need to find the proper arguments needed to do what you want. (for exemple usually the defaults hides lost of things, and truncates system calls arguments to only the first few charaters, etc : all this can be changed with options)

And see if it outputs things on stderr (probably). And wrap it in a script that act accordingly to what you need it to do. (for ex:  2>/some/tracefile # and have anothe script  tail -f /some/tracefile and act when it see this or that system call appear.)

Comment: Hey Oliver, thanks for your answer, but unfortunately my original question wasn't clear: I was looking for programmatic interfaces that could provide this data.

Comment: @Alexander : your programm can : attach a truss/ strace /struss / whatever to the pid it wants to monitor, and monitor its output to detect any occurence of exec, execve, etc ?  Otherwise there may be an equivalent system call (see the source file of strace / truss / dtruss to find out how they make it work)

Comment: Oh that's a neat idea. I'm not sure how much of that stuff is exposed in public APIs, but I'll peak at the source and try it out!

Comment: @alexander:  exec is a system call, not an executable per se. In unix: when you call an exec variant (execve, etc) it "replaces" your program space with the code of the programm "exec"-ed ... so you would see with dtruss : a call with for exemple :  execve(..."/path/to/newprogram"....)  (with arguments before/after? depending on the way that system call is defined). if it is instead a fork, you would see a call to the forking system command, and then need to follow its children to see the children forked process system calls afterwards.